# How can I become more competent in the lab?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, education

I'm currently taking an introduction to Newtonian mechanics class(calculus-based) and I am laughably bad in the lab. So far I have a pretty solid grasp on the concepts ,but applying those concepts to solve the problems in lab seems to be more difficult for me than others. I'm pretty competent at solving problems in the book, so I would assume that would carry into the labs, but sadly it doesn't. I love physics and the reasoning behind it, but if I continue down this path I think I am destined to fail. Any advice on how to become a more well-rounded lab rat would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should practice critical thinking and troubleshooting. i have a lab partner who is also laughably bad because they cannot find ways to test why things that work in theory are not working in reality in the lab. i think the reason this can be hard is because people get caught up on what "should" work instead of really troubleshooting what each piece of equipment is interpreting. maybe you can try to have this mindset?

Comment: https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_Introductory_Physics_-_Building_Models_to_Describe_Our_World_(Martin_Neary_Rinaldo_and_Woodman)/02%3A_Comparing_Model_and_Experiment/2.03%3A_Making_Measurements  , https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.5145420, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fundamentals_of_Physics/Physics_and_Measurement

Comment: Welcome @Mail-Sail. If you post a question about a specific experimental problem, you might get a response; I suggest tagging it [experimental-physics] as well as [education]. Relativisitccucumber's advice is very good. Experiments rarely work first time, so persistence is essential in both first year and the most cutting edge research labs. One of the biggest challenges in traditional introductory physics labs is that students simply don't have time to resolve the inevitable problems, and it working through those issues is where the most important learning occurs. Don't give up!

Comment: Team up with somebody who is good at these things. A few days into my first semester a future theorist approached me and asked me if I wanted to study with him. He is a much, much better physicist than I am but he didn't know how to hold a screwdriver straight. Somehow he picked up that I like to work with hardware and he was smart to know and admit his limitations. So he did the best thing for both of us and got himself a handyman. We became best buddies for the next five years. I got him through all the experimental stuff and (only) thanks to him I didn't fail the theory classes.